# How to return a value from a regular javascript function that contains a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

```
function bsfir() {
    Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
        return Parse.Cloud.run('gRFI', {});
    }).then(function(gRFIr) {
        return Parse.Cloud.run('gFI', { });
    }).then(function(gFIR) {
        return gFIR;
    }, function(error) {
        return error;
    });
}

Parse.Cloud.define("bSFI", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
        return bsfir();
    }).then(function(bsfirr) {
        response.success(bsfirr);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("219 error: " + JSON.stringify( error));
    });
});
```

The goal is to have `bsfir()` complete execution (i.e. resolve the promise) before handing execution back to the caller, in this case, `bSFI()`.

Calling `bSFI()` results in executing only a few lines of code in `bsfir()`.  The execution of `bSFI()` completes almost immediately/instantaneously probably because the promise in `bsfir()` isn't tied to a return value so when `bSFI()` calls `bsfir()`, execution immediately goes to `response.success(bsfirr);`

Is using `Promise.all()` in `bsfir()` a good solution?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. All you can do is return a promise. There is no way to make an asynchronous action synchronous.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, returning a promise will work also. Only a 1 or 2 lines of code in bsfir() are executed in the split second that it takes to call bsfir() then execution continues in the caller, & the rest of the code in bsfir() don't get a chance to be run. In many other scenarios, it works perfectly if I were to change bsfir() into cloud code.  bSFI() will call bsfir() and after bsfir() completes 100%, the return value from bsfir() is returned to bSFI() then execution will continue in bSFI() as expected.  But since bsfir() is a regular javascript function, it's not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot wait for the promise to resolve before you return. Your task is asynchronous, but the `return` must happen immediately.

But what you can do is to simply return the promise (from your) itself, and allow your caller to wait for it. In fact, your `bSFI()` already uses promise anyway, so it is trivial to integrate.

```
function bsfir() {
    return Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
//  ^^^^^^
        return Parse.Cloud.run('gRFI', {});
    }).then(function(gRFIr) {
        return Parse.Cloud.run('gFI', {});
    });
}

Parse.Cloud.define("bSFI", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Promise.as().then(bsfir).then(function(bsfirr) {
        response.success(bsfirr);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("219 error: " + JSON.stringify( error));
    });
});
```

Notice that you should be able to replace `Parse.Promise.as().then(…)` by just `…()` in both functions.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, do you have time to work on a bigger project long term?

Comment: @HenrySitu: Sorry, I'm not for hire if you mean that, and not in LA for sure.

Comment: @Bergi - am I missing something?  The first, empty promise in the chain seems to me superfluous.  Why not `return Parse.Cloud.run('gRFI', {}).then() {...` ?  Cloud.run() returns a promise.  That should be the start of the chain, right?

Comment: @Bergi thanks. If anything comes up, please let me know.  We can always contribute to a project virtually together using something like github.

Comment: @danh: Yes, it's superfluous, that's what I meant by my last paragraph. I just didn't want to change the OP's code too much, so that it is more obvious where the `return` was missing.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi Appreciate it.